# Laravel eloquent query improvement

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Currently I've got this eloquent query:

```
$products = Product::where('is_send', 1)->with(['articles.stock' => function($query) {
            $query->where('quantity', '>', 0);
        }])->get();
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way for doing this?

***For clarification:***

A **product** hasMany **articles**

A **article** hasOne **Stock**

I need the `article_ids` where **product** `is_send = 1` and where the **articles** of that **product** have quantity `> then 0`.

Comment: is this working?? add your table column info with the questions

Comment: If you could filter articles by something it would be good but if not then it's either this query or a 3 table join. A 3 table join might be slightly quicker. However the question is, does stock really need to be a separate entity from article since it appears to be 1 to 1

Comment: I agree with @apokryfos, you are best off with the query you presented, all you can do is optimize it by creating a scope, this applies if you are using or going to be using it a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing this query a lot, then you can create a scope, here is an example:

**Product model code**

```
public function scopeltStockQuantity($query, $quantity) {
    return $query->with(['articles.stock' => function($innerQuery) use ($quantity) {
        $innerQuery->where('quantity', '>', $quantity);
    }]);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$products = Product::where('is_send', 1)->ltStockQuantity(0)->get();
```

Or to further separate the code you can do something like this:

**Stock model code**

```
public function scopeltQuantity($query, $quantity) {
    return $query->where('quantity', '>', $quantity);
}
```

**Product model code**

```
public function scopeltStockQuantity($query, $quantity) {
    return $query->with(['articles.stock' => function($innerQuery) use ($quantity) {
        $innerQuery->ltQuantity($quantity);
    }]);
}
```